# How to trace a java application running on a remote host

Tags: java, remote-debugging, trace

I know the tool **btrace** that allows you to print the method calls as they are executed. But it doesn't seem to work for a java app running on a remote host.

I don't need a thread dump. I what to see what classes and methods are affected when a particular use case is executed. They should be printed as soon as they are called. How to achieve it?

Comment: have you use logger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found a tool that is able to do this:

**InTrace**

http://mchr3k.github.io/org.intrace/

It doesn't take process ID as parameter but intstead of if host name of IP address and port number of a remote host. So it clearly works with remote java processes.

I've already tested it myself. It prints all I need - full class name, method name, arguments and even line number.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/documentation.html). Its free and comes bundled with jdk.

It shows thread view, class view. However, it doesn't show method calls view.
If you need a method calls view, use a profiler such as JProfiler or Yourkit java profiler.

Comment: It is better to say that VisualVM is installed together with java so that no one starts searching this free utility ;)

Comment: @ka3ak yes agreed. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -3):

U should use logger for this. You can trace each method call by using debug and info logs with logger.